# OpenGL rotation, rotating the wrong direction, what is wrong?

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I have a very simple pyramid shape made up of 6 triangles defined this way:

```
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, // front triange
    0, 3, 4, // back triangle
    0, 3, 1, // left side triangle
    0, 2, 4, // right side triangle
    1, 3, 4, // square base triangle 1
    4, 2, 1  // square base triangle 2
};

float pyramid[] = {
    0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // top of the pyramid

// base vertices (a square)
   -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, // left front
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, // right front
   -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // left back
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // right back
};
```

I am trying to rotate it around the Y axis, but when I do so, it is not rotating continously, it ends up rotating a bit to left, and then rotating a bit to right, left-right, left-right and so on, but never does a full 360 degree rotation.

My rotation code is this:

```
glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.7f));
glm::mat4 rotate = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 worldView = rotate * scale;

glUniformMatrix4fv(hWorld, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(worldView));
```

The `angle` I am incrementing it in every loop:

```
static float angle = 0.0f;
angle += 0.001f;
```

I am giving up, so I hope someone could shed some light on my mistake.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 world;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = world * vec4(0.5 * pos, 1.0f);
    color = 8 * vec4(clamp(pos, 0.0f, 0.1f), 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Why do you translate the matrix in the uniform command?

Comment: Using glm you dont need to transpose them, as they are already built column major by default

Comment: Updated the question with my vertex shader. As for the uniform, I just use the example from: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial11/tutorial11.html

Comment: I swapped it to FALSE, but still not working as expected.

Comment: Is it allowed here to link (attach) the full source?

Comment: From what I understood in your code, the `world` matrix is the model matrix, but where are the view & projection matrices? You are describing the problem as a wrong visual output, which could be cause by other things than the rotation itself. Also, you can debug wether the rotation is working within the host by printing any of the vertex of your pyramid multiplied by the model matrix, and see if the output you get is the expected.

Comment: The expected look is a cone floating and rotating around in 3d space. Now I tried to port it as best I could and mine is jumping all around. I asked my question also here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/200584-What-is-wrong-with-my-code-%28rotation%29

Comment: I did not know that order of the vertices matter!! :/

Comment: I messed them up.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I mixed up the vertex arrays:

```
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, // front triange
    0, 3, 4, // back triangle
    0, 3, 1, // left side triangle
    0, 2, 4, // right side triangle
    1, 3, 4, // square base triangle 1
    4, 2, 1  // square base triangle 2
};
```

Should be:

```
   // index array
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 3, 1,
        0, 4, 3,
        0, 2, 4,
        1, 3, 4,
        4, 2, 1 
    };
```

The order of the vertices should go **counter clockwise.**